# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() error after filter data according to login user

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to filter data according to login user.before i filter the data by Login user it was work fine. now it shows an error

> Severity: 4096
>
> Message: Object of class Floor_model could not be converted to string
>
> Filename: models/Book_model.php
>
> Line Number: 14
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Object of class Floor_model to string conversion
>
> Filename: models/Book_model.php
>
> Line Number: 14

**View**

```
<?php foreach($post as $post){?>
 <tr>
     <td><?php echo $post->id ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td>
     <td><?php echo $post->title ; echo '&nbsp; &nbsp;';?></td>
 </tr>  
<?php } ?>
```

**Model**

```
 function get_book(){
    $id = $this->session->$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];// getting id
    $this->db->select("book.id,book.title");
    $this->db->where('user_id', $id);//
    $this->db->from('book');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function index(){ 
   $data['post'] = $this->floor_model->get_book(); 
   $this->load->view('user_include/header'); 
   $this->load->view('plan/floor',$data); 
}
```

Comment: check Line Number: 14 in model You are passing an object and using it as string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In model change

```
$this->session->$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];
```

to

```
$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];
```

and try once

Comment: this error is solved.but it not filter data.plz help me

Comment: you mean the problem is with query??

Comment: my problem is filter data according to login user id.but its not working

Comment: Is the value stored in session correct?? i mean are you storing correct logged in user's id in session?? Coz, rest everythig is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87585/discussion-between-ashik-and-niranjan).